# Is using Javascript to modify a div content a good method for an entire website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently developing my own portfolio and I have a few questions on which architecture to use.

At the moment, I have an `index.html` page that has all the information I want to display when someone arrives on the website. I also have a `/views/` folder, in which I have the rest of the content (like `cv.html`, `about_me.html`...)

When I click on an element from my menu, it loads the appropriate content into my "content" div, using jQuery. So the user always stays on the same page (the index page), but the content changes.

However, I am trying to make the website available in different languages, and I am wondering about how to do that. I thought about having an `/eng/` folder in my `/views/` folder, with only HTML content in english. I would then check if the language is set to english in order to know which content to include in the page using jQuery.

But I don't know how exactly I would do that, how good that method is, or which method to use for that matter. Also, is using Javascript to change a div content the way I do a good practice ? What would you recommend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a nice solution right there.

In your javascript-file simply declare a variable for the language with a default value.

```
var lang = 'eng';
```

When loading pages:

```
$('#link').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var path_to_load 'views/'+lang+'/'+$(this).attr('href');
        // Do normal .load or .ajax here
});
```

When changing language you could have buttons or links with `data-lang-code="eng"` or `data-lang-code="no"`, or anything you like.

```
$('.lang_choices').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    lang = $(this).data('lang-code');
    // Load frontpage for the new language here.
});
```

EDIT: This solution is built upon the idea of subfolders for different languages in your `/views/`-folder.

SUPEREDIT: About the last question you ask. Using ajax to load parts of the page is very typical WEB2.0. Just look at how Facebook is doing it. Less refresh = quicker loadingtime. In addition you have many neat features when working with ajax. Fading content in, having the div animate to one of the sides and the new content "fly" in from the other side. I am trying to use ajax as much as possible where I see fit. Unless your site is supercomplex and has a lot of different design (it does not look that way from your question), I would suggest staying with this solution.

Comment: Wow thanks! I really like this solution. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your question: "Is a simple solution good for a simple problem?".

Don't over engineer.